# Show all Dates data between two dates; if no row exists for particular date then show zero in all columns using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

folks I m stuck in logical or syntax problem, I have tried so many thing from stack. But I didn't get the exact solution on my Problem.

**Problem**

I have table abc with following columns

```
╔════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ success ║ transactionTime     ║ value ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 1  ║ 1       ║ 2018/09/12 10:50:00 ║ 10    ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2  ║ 0       ║ 2018/09/13 10:58:00 ║ 12    ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 3  ║ 1       ║ 2018/09/13 10:55:00 ║ 34    ║
╚════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

I wanted Show All the data between two dates; if no row exists for particular date then show zero in all columns using sequelize ;

> I understand with the SQL but not getting how to do with Sequilze ORM

I have Tried this

```
startDate = moment().subtract(7, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00');
endDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59');  
const Record = await db.abc.count({
        where: {
         transactionTime: {
            $between: [
              startDate, 
              endDate,
            ],
          },
        },
        attributes: [[sequelize.fn('DATE_FORMAT', sequelize.col('transactionTime'), '%Y-%m-%d'), 'day']],
        group: [sequelize.fn('DAY', sequelize.col('transactionTime'))],
      });
```

**I Am getting the following Output**

```
day              Count
2018/09/12        1
2018/09/13        2
```

**Expected Output :**

```
day              Count
2018/09/08        0
2018/09/09        0
2018/09/10        0
2018/09/11        0
2018/09/12        1
2018/09/13        2
```

Help me out, I am new in sequelize.

Comment: You're basically fine with what you've got. Just handle the logic of the missing results in your display code. Loop through the result, and if there's no match for the given day, then print 0

Comment: If you ended up trying to do this in SQL you'd end up having to JOIN against a table containing the range of days. I'm with @Strawberry it seems, handle the gaps in the application code.

Comment: @Strawberry exactly you are right, but i m not getting how to use the union or how to place the condition between the logic.